# Convert csv text from utf-16 to ascii or read in correctly

Tags: python, csv, encoding, ascii, utf

I have problems while reading text from a csv file. 
An example line from the csv file looks like this:"

> 1477-7819-4-45-2   Angiolymphatic Invasion (H & E 400 Ã)."

I guess that the problem is the coding of the text, so I decided to change it to ASCII.

This is my python code so far:

```
text_path = '/some_path/filename.csv'
text_path_ascii = '/some_path/filename_ASCII.csv'

input_codec = 'UTF-16'
output_codec = 'ASCII'

for line in unicode_file:
    unicode_data = unicode_file.read().decode(input_codec)
    #here is another problem => AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
    unicode_data = unicode_file.read()

ascii_file = open(text_path_ascii, 'w')
ascii_file.write(unicode_data.write(unicode_data.encode(output_codec)))
# same problem=> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encode'
ascii_file.write(unicode_data.encode(output_codec))
```

So my problem is that I don't know how to encode/decode the text.

I am even not sure if this is the right way to handle the wrong written text (yes, the text looks like the given line if you open it with any editor) correcly.

Or is there maybe an easier way to read in the csv text without "broken" characters) directly?

Thanks for Your ideas

Comment: Oups, I could not exactly understand what you are trying to do here, but you are taking a wrong path! And a str object shall have encode method in Python3 and decode method in Python2. Having none of them is an evidence that something wrong is happening. And either Python2 and Python3 are able to process non ascii csv files, unfortunately differently. So, say what Python version you use (Python3 is more unicode friendly), show some lines of your input file and say whay is its encoding. We could then say how to load it as a csv file...

Comment: The first (and last) thing to try is to read the text file with the encoding it was written with. If you didn't receive that information with the file, specification or documentation, send it back. If you received the file through HTTP, perhaps there is a Content-Type header that tells you what the encoding ("charset") is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `decode` method on `str` but it is on [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#bytes.decode)

If you want to decode it. You can do it with `open` itself.

```
file = open(filename, mode, encoding='utf-8')
```